# How to remove header and footer of a iframe on printing - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm having a problem by trying to print a iframe on my page. Imagine that i have this:

```
<iframe id="printMe">Some data..</iframe>
```

I'm using this code (example)

```
<script>document.getElementById("printf").contentWindow.print()​​​​​​;</script>
```

After this i put a button to print only what is inside the iframe, but when I print, it aways come with the default header and footer. How can I block this to happen? thanks.

Comment: set some @media=print styles that suppress the stuff you don't want?

Comment: but what is the class or element that i need to suppress? in this case i want to suppress the default information like date.. and stuff.. but i really don't know the selector to do it.

Comment: how should we know? You haven't shown any html. you'd have to look at the page structure and figure it out.

Comment: If I understand you correctly that is not possible as it is added by the browser itself.